# SetConsoleMode returning false when enabling ANSI color under Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, windows-console

I've recently upgraded one of my PCs from windows 7 pro to windows 10 pro. I'm trying to run some code that I know is working on another windows 10 machine (that was win10 pro from the beginning). In both cases, I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017, target platform is Windows 10 and the platform toolset is v141. I've tried a few different windows SDK versions, which hasn't changed the results. Debug and release mode builds behave the same way. The application is run from visual studio with the usual "start without debugging". Running it from a console externally to visual studio makes no difference.

This is pretty much the example code that MS provide for enabling ANSI colour mode in a terminal application:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  DWORD consoleMode;
  GetConsoleMode(hConsole, &consoleMode);
  consoleMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;

  if (!SetConsoleMode(hConsole, consoleMode))
  {
    auto e = GetLastError();
    std::cout << "error " << e << "\n";
  }
  else
    std::cout << "\x1b[32mgreen\n";
}
```

On the upgraded machine, `SetConsoleMode` returns false, and `GetLastError` returns 87 ("*The parameter is incorrect*") and ANSI colour codes are not handled by the console in subsequent output. On the other machine, this all succeeds just fine and ansi colors are rendered as expected.

Opening up a console window on the upgraded machine shows *Version 10.0.10240*, and on the other machine it shows *Version 10.0.14393*. Although I'm slightly suprised that the upgraded machine isn't running a more recent version, the version it is running should support ANSI color.

What could explain the difference in behavior between the two machines?

Comment: You need to call `GetLastError` **immediately** after the call to `SetConsoleMode` fails. Your code has lots of C++ code in between, and it's not safe to assume, that the error code really is the one you state. Anyway, [ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033.aspx) can only be used, *"if the* hConsoleHandle *parameter is a screen buffer handle"*.

Comment: That makes no difference to the fact that `SetConsoleMode` fails unexpectedly, and that the same code running under two machines that should show the same behaviour isn't showing any such thing. I've made a trivial edit to the code, and the error code is exactly the same, unsurprisingly.

Comment: The difference is, that we don't know the details of the error mode. It could be error code 87, or something else altogether. No need to throw a hissy fit, when someone points out an obvious source of confusion.

Comment: Even if there were no call to `GetLastError` at all, the same code, being built and run in the same way on the same operating system should behave the same way on both. Why would running it on one machine provide a screen buffer handle, and running it on the other not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Support for ANSI escape sequences in console windows was not added until Windows 10 Threshold 2 (TH2), also known as the "November Update", which is version 1511 and has the build number 10586.

Your "other machine", with version 10.0.14393, therefore has full support when you pass the appropriate flag to `SetConsoleMode`. However, the "upgraded machine", with version 10.0.10240, does not recognize the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag and is therefore returning an "Invalid Parameter" error.

In fact, this is the [officially recommended way to check whether the OS supports the extended console features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032.aspx):

> The following code provides an example of the recommended way to enable virtual terminal processing for an application. The intent of the sample is to demonstrate:
>
> 1. The existing mode should always be retrieved via `GetConsoleMode` and analyzed before being set with `SetConsoleMode`.
> 2. `SetConsoleMode` returning with `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` is the current mechanism to determine when running on a down-level system. An application receiving `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` with one of the newer console mode flags in the bit field should gracefully degrade behavior and try again.

As a workaround on downlevel systems, you could use [ANSICon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) or [ConEmu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/).

Comment: Using a library such as PDCurses or something else that abstracts the Windows console API may be a better alternative than ANSICON, which is based on DLL injection and API hooking.

Comment: These alternatives are a bit beyond my area of expertise, @eryksun, so thanks for sharing that. If you like, feel free to edit a link to the project you describe into the answer so it doesn't get missed.

Comment: Here's a link to the GitHub page for [PDCurses](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses). Using a curses library is a major commitment, but the payoff hopefully is a console/terminal app that's more portable across platforms.

Comment: So, as Eryksun has deleted his earlier comment, the update I apparently needed but for some reason didn't have was the "Creator's Update", which included all the necessary updates and also added the windows bulid number to the system-about page (explaining why I couldn't find that before, too).